# How to add so many divider?

Tags: android, divider

Hi guys i have a app with just a relative layout and i have lot of medium size text like say i have ten medium size text.

I want to add a divider/separator below every text.

I have tried by this

```
<View
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "1dp"
android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
```

But its very hard for me to arrange them every time manually. I have to do this on lot of different activity

So please tell me the easiest way to do this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` and include `android:layout_below` to align it below your text.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textidhere"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#dcddde"
        android:layout_below="@id/textidhere"/>
```

Comment: Glad to be able to help. :)